# Uploading 100,000 rows into a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sqlbulkcopy

What's the fastest way to upload bulk (over 100,000 records) from an ASP.NET MVC application?

I tried using the following methods:

1. `BulkCopy` but I keep getting this error:

> Message: Error writing to CustomerUPLLimit Table.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)

2. Used Entity Framework `InsertRangeAsync` but that takes a lot of time. 30,000 records took over 30 minutes

Comment: The bulk copy message is pretty straightforward. It says that it cannot connect using the provided connection string.

Comment: <add name="ExcelDB" connectionString="data source=*******;initial catalog=****;persist security info=True;user id=***;password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;" />

that's the connection string. It works when trying to insert few records of less than a 1000 but fails when the records gets larger

Answer (score 1):

BULK INSERT will be very fast approach for inserting huge amount of data.

1. Get format file as given below:

```
BCP DbName.SchemaName.TableName format nul 
-x -S ServerName -c -f c:\dev\TableFormat.xml -t, -T
```

2. Now, BULK INSERT into the table using the csv file, containing the data, and format file.

```sql
BULK INSERT dbo.TableName
FROM 'c:\dev\TableData.csv'
WITH (FORMATFILE = 'C:\dev\TableFormat.xml');
```

Comment: I'm fetching the data from an excel file using EPPlus. The DB is also hosted on a different server from the Web Application

Answer (score 0):

I want to recomment EFCore.BulkExtensions [here](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions)

```
context.BulkInsert(entitiesList);                 context.BulkInsertAsync(entitiesList);
context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(entitiesList);         context.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(entitiesList);      //Upsert
context.BulkInsertOrUpdateOrDelete(entitiesList); context.BulkInsertOrUpdateOrDeleteAsync(entitiesList);//Sync
context.BulkUpdate(entitiesList);                 context.BulkUpdateAsync(entitiesList);
context.BulkDelete(entitiesList);                 context.BulkDeleteAsync(entitiesList);
context.BulkRead(entitiesList);                   context.BulkReadAsync(entitiesList);
context.Truncate<Entity>();                       context.TruncateAsync<Entity>();
```